# Parsing 12,000+ XML files

Tags: awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I have a folder that contains 12,000+ XML files. I need to get a list of files within that folder that meet certain criteria.

In the XML file there is a node called `/BillingData/InvoiceLinesList/InvoiceLines`. There could be one or more `InvoiceLines` within the `InvoiceLinesList`. In the `InvoiceLines`, I need to search for a tag called `<charge>` whose value is `99` and also where there is a tag in the same `InvoiceLines` called `<chargeType>` where the value is `D`.

What's the best way to do that? Using `awk` I thought I might be able to do it, but I couldn't figure a way of searching for multiple conditions as I'm not great at `awk`. I saw a potential method on here using `xmlstarlet` but that only looks for one or other value in a single tag rather than separate values in more than one tag.

Comment: for xml, use xml tools. do not parse XML/HMTL/json/yaml without the appropriate tool. When you desperately need  to hammer a nail and have no hammer, you cn use a heavy object instead but it's uncomfortable and risky. It's the same with parsing XML, if you can use appropriate tool do it, it will be easier safer and the result will only be nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `awk` and `sed` are generally unsuitable for parsing XML (and other similar formats such as JSON and YAML etc.).  For this XML example, for example, we don't know what order the nodes in `InvoiceLines` are stored or whether they are delimited by newlines or not. The XML format does not care about these things, but an `awk` or `sed` script would fall over easily unless exceptional care was taken to cover all possible cases (including the various possible encodings of the data), in which case you would have had to write an XML parser anyway.

So, using an XML parser, like the one built into `xmlstarlet`, is the right thing to want to do.

---

The following command would print the filename of the input file if at least one of the required nodes was found in the file `file.xml`.  If multiple `InvoiceLines` nodes matched, the filename would be printed multiple times with a newline in-between.  This means that we, from the start, disqualify filenames containing newlines.

```
xmlstarlet sel \
    -t -m '/BillingData/InvoiceLinesList/InvoiceLines[chargeType = "D" and charge = "99"]' \
    --inp-name -nl file.xml
```

The XPATH query would match all `InvoiceLines` that had subnodes `chargeType` and `charge` with the specified values.  Using `@charge` instead of `charge` would have tested against a `charge` *attribute* in the `InvoiceLines` node, by the way.

Applying this on all XML files in a single directory:

```
xmlstarlet sel \
    -t -m '/BillingData/InvoiceLinesList/InvoiceLines[chargeType = "D" and charge = "99"]' \
    --inp-name -nl ./*.xml
```

If there are too many files and the above throws an error, you may use `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\n' ./*.xml | xargs xmlstarlet -t -m ...
```

Or, `find` (this will also search subdirectories):

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet -t -m ... {} +
```

Pipe the result through `uniq` if you want to make the file listing unique.

---

I used the following XML to test the above:

```
<BillingData>
    <InvoiceLinesList>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <chargeType>D</chargeType>
            <charge>99</charge>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <chargeType>D</chargeType>
            <charge>99</charge>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <chargeType>E</chargeType>
            <charge>99</charge>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </InvoiceLinesList>
</BillingData>
```

Comment: Does `xmlstarlet` still load the whole file in memory before proceding? Good luck with that ;-)

Comment: @mosvy Do you know how big the files are?  The main part of the answer is the XPATH query.  This could be applied with some other framework if needs be.

Comment: @Kusalananda That looks amazing. The XML structure you used as a test is correct. There are other nodes but their names are different. The XML is well formed so I will give your example a shot and see how it goes. Kudos dude!

Comment: So as a single command I tried xmlstarlet sel \ -t -m '/BillingData/InvoiceLinesList/InvoiceLines[chargeType = "D" and charge = "99"]' \ --inp-name -nl ./*.xml but it gave me an error: error in arguments: no -t or --template options found

Comment: @snert the backslashes ( \ ) escapes the newlines in my command.  If you put it on a single line, then remove them.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the case. I tried it. I replaced -nl with --nl and also tried -n as they seem to do the same thing and I get "failed to load external entity "./*.xml""

Comment: This is xmlstarlet under cygwin by the way as I have to use Windows at work and this is about the only way I can get linux tools

Comment: @snert A pro tip is to install you favourite Unix in a VirtualBox virtual machine.  That way you don't have to conform to Windows too much.  I worked like that for years (OpenBSD in VirtualBox on top of Windows).

Comment: @snert `-nl` should definitely only have one dash (and I don't know what `-n` is, don't just try deleting or adding random characters!).  The `./*.xml` should expand to the filenames that you want to process.  The fact that it doesn't tells me that there are no XML files in the current directory.

Comment: Am I being dumb or something but how do I mark a response as the answer?

Comment: @snert If you want to mark an answer as "accepted", you should click on the check-mark beneath the vote-up/vote-down buttons. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers